# Return record even if nested where clause does not match

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables - one where I keep all the sessions for a course(course_sessions) and another (student_session_attendance) where we keep students attendance for a particular session. Now I need to retrieve a students attendance data for a particular course. So, I pick all the sessions for a course and then for those session, I look into student_session_attendance. Challenge is, students can get added midway or leave midway in which case we will not have data for every session for every student. But, what I need is a blank row from table student_session_attendance even if a student's information for a particular session is not there. Here's my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM student_session_attendance
WHERE student_id = 764 AND sessions_id IN
(SELECT id FROM course_sessions WHERE batch_id = 18);
```

I've also tried this:

```
SELECT A.id AS sessionid, A.batch_id, A.session_date, B.student_id, B.sessions_id, B.attendance
FROM course_sessions A
LEFT JOIN student_session_attendance B ON A.id = B.sessions_id
WHERE A.batch_id = 18
```

So, if a course has 5 sessions - course_sessions will have 5 rows. But student_session_attendance may have only 3 rows for a particular student who is attending that course. But I need all 5 rows with two null for missing rows.

Thanks,
Vikalp Jain

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should change the `WHERE` clause to a join condition. So instead of `WHERE` you should use `AND`.

Comment: The 2nd query looks fine for the purpose. what was the problem with it?